# Vue doesn't re-render component after third time updating property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have the following code that either assigns or removes an existing 'role' to a user:

```
    onAddRole(role) {
        let roles = this.user.roles
        roles.push(role)

        this.$set(this.user, roles)

        console.log(this.user.roles)

        this.success.role_update = true
    },

    onRoleDelete(selected_role) {
        let i = this.user.roles.map(role => role.id).indexOf(selected_role.id)

        if (i !== -1) {
            let roles = this.user.roles

            roles.splice(i, 1)

            this.$set(this.user, roles)

            console.log(this.user.roles)

            this.success.role_update = true
        }
    }
```

Here is my data property for the component:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        user: null,
        success: {
            permission: null,
            invalidation: null,
            fetch: null,
            save: null,
            role_update: null
        },
        loading: false
    }
},
```

And here is a snippet of the relevant html:

```
    <b-row>
        <b-col md="6">
            <b-row v-if="user">
                <b-col md="12">
                    <user-roles
                        :user="user"
                        @add_role="onAddRole"
                        @set_role="onRoleSet"
                        @role_failure="roleFail"
                        @role_delete="onRoleDelete"
                    />
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
            <loading v-if="loading" />
        </b-col>
    </b-row>
```

Basically this code works fine if I add a role once or twice. However, after the third time I remove or add a user role, Vue stops re-rendering the component. Any ideas why this would happen?

The console.logs show that the property itself is updated correctly, but the view does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to having it work consistently was to separate the roles property from users, like so:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        user: null,
        roles: null,
        success: {
            permission: null,
            invalidation: null,
            fetch: null,
            save: null,
            role_update: null
        },
        loading: false
    }
},
```

then just update the roles property for the event handler methods like you normally would. no need to use `.$set`:

```
    onRoleSet({ role, i }) {
        this.roles.splice(i, 1, role)

        this.success.role_update = true
    },

    onAddRole(role) {
        this.roles.push(role)

        this.success.role_update = true
    },

    onRoleDelete(selected_role) {
        let i = this.roles.map(role => role.id).indexOf(selected_role.id)

        if (i !== -1) {
            this.roles.splice(i, 1)

            this.success.role_update = true
        }
    }
```

so far this is working consistently for me and the component updates like it's supposed to.

It seems that having a nested property in the component's `data` object seems to cause me a lot of problems with Vue, so it's best to avoid doing that

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the final resolution but I see two issues that may be the root cause.

Whenever you do:

`let roles = this.user.roles`

you're creating a reference to that array so when you next do:

`roles.push(role)`

You're actually just essentially doing

`this.user.roles.push(role)`

So really there's not much of a reason to even allocate the `let roles` variable.

Secondly, `this.$set` needs the name of the property.  So it should be

`this.$set(this.user, 'roles', roles)`

or you'll be creating an undefined property on the user with `roles` assigned to it.

I'm not quite sure why you're using `this.$set` though since your already modifying the roles when you `push()` and it would just be assigning the same array back to the property the way you're currently doing it.

Comment: i think i had to use this.$set because the component doesn't know about the nested .roles property of user, so i have to explicitly set it that way. i'll try just doing this.user.roles.push and see if that possibly works though. otherwise i can try setting roles as an explicit property of the component, separate from user